# Update Multiple Input Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to update multiple inputs in Laravel? I have two tables: `Order` and `Detail_Order`. Here's my controller to create multiple inputs.

```
public function store($id_trip, Request $request){
    $order = new Order();
    $order->id_trip = $id_trip;
    $order->id_users = Auth::guard('operator')->user()->id_users;            
    $order->date_order = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $order->id_users_operator = Auth::guard('operator')->user()->id_users;
    $order->save();

    foreach($request->passenger_name as $key => $value){
        Detail_Order::create([
            'id_trip' => $order->id_trip,
            'id_seat' => $request->id_seat[$key],
            'id_order' => $order->id_order,
            'passenger_name' => $request->passenger_name[$key],
            'address' => $request->address[$key],
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number[$key]
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to update it, but I don't know how to update the Detail_order. Here's my update controller :

```
    public function update($id_order, $id_trip, Request $request){

        $order = Order::where(['id_order' => $id_order, 'id_trip' => $id_trip])->first();
        $order->id_trip = $request->id_trip;
        $order->id_users = Auth::guard('operator')->user()->id_users;            
        $order->save();

        $detail = Detail_Order::where(['id_order' => $id_order, 'id_trip' => $id_trip])->get();

        if(count($request->id_seat) > 0){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($request->id_seat); $i++){
                $detail[$i]->id_trip = $order->id_trip;
                $detail[$i]->id_seat = $request->id_seat[$i];
                $detail[$i]->id_order = $pesanan->id_order;
                $detail[$i]->passenger_name = $request->passenger_name[$i];
                $detail[$i]->address = $request->address[$i];
                $detail[$i]->phone_number = $request->phone_number[$i];
                $detail[$i]->save();
            }
        }

     session()->flash('flash_success', 'Data has been updated');
     return redirect('/order');
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Your title asking for updating multiple Inputs, but your code shows creating objects based on input fields set in the request object. Do you like to update multiple inputs on the webpage after running the store function or what kind of multiple input you are referring to?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to edit multiple inputs when I click button edit on the webpage and it's showing the input form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after  `$order->save();` line you can do something like this....
if it is work good .. if not you can comment below . i will give you solution...

```
$order->save();

 $detail =  Detail_Order::where('order_id', $order->id)->get();

if(count($request->id_seat) > 0){

    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->id_seat); $i++){
        
        $detail[$i]->order_id = $order->id;
        $detail[$i]->id_seat = $request->id_seat[$i],
        $detail[$i]->passenger_name = $request->passenger_name[$i];
        $detail[$i]->save();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it says `Undefined variable: i`

Comment: remove $i variable from both count($request->id_seat) function.

Comment: you are welcome.. and i am also update your question ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216857/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-beginner).

Comment: Hi, I have some errors, if you're not busy perhaps you could check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006021/api-create-multiple-input-laravel) . Thank you