# API Create Multiple Input Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I'm currently creating API for multiple inputs using laravel. The data will be stored into two tables : `Order` and `Detail_Order`. One order can have many detail orders.
But now, the data only stored into `Order` table, and got an error: `ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file`. Does anyone know how? Thank you.

Here's my code :

```
public function createDetail($total_passenger, $id_trip, $id_users, Request $request){

    $trip = Trip::where(['id_trip' => $id_trip])->get();

    $seat = $request->id_seat;
        if(Detail_Order::where(['id_trip' => $id_trip, 'id_seat' => $seat])
            ->where('status', '!=', 5)
            ->exists()) {
                   
                return $this->error("Seat has been booked");
        }else{
                $order = new Order();
                $order_select = Order::select('id_order');
                $order_count = $order_select->count();
                    if ($order_count === 0) {
                        $order->id_order = 'P1';
                    }else{
                        $lastrow=$order_select->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
                        $lastrow_id = explode('P', $lastrow->id_order);
                        $new_id = $lastrow_id[1]+1;
                        $order->id_order = 'P'.$new_id;
                    }
            $order->id_trip = $id_trip;
            $order->id_users = $id_users;            
            $order->date_order = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $order->id_users_operator = 'O4';
            $order->save();

                foreach($request->passenger_name as $key => $value){
                Detail_Order::create([
                    'id_trip' => $order->id_trip,
                    'id_seat' => $request->id_seat[$key],
                    'id_order' => $order->id_order,
                    'passenger_name' => $request->passenger_name[$key],
                    'gender' => $request->gender[$key],
                    'departure' => $request->departure[$key],
                    'destination' => $request->destination[$key],
                    'phone' => $request->phone[$key],
                    'status' => 1
                    ]);
                }    
            
        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => "Successfully saved data",
            'data' => $order
        ]);

}
```

Comment: is `$request->passenger_name` an array? you have to pass an array to `foreach`.

Comment: side note: you can change 'passenger_name' => $request->passenger_name[$key], to 'passenger_name' => $value,

Comment: hi..  did you check  `$request->passenger_name` an array ?